# write text file with new line

Tags: php

I am using following method to write into log.txt

```
public function write($message, $file=null, $user=null)
{
    $message = date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time())  .' - '.$message;
    $message .= is_null($file) ? '' : " in $file";
    $message .= is_null($user) ? '' : " by $user";
    $message .= "\n";
    return file_put_contents( $this->logfile, $message, FILE_APPEND );
}
```

but when i check track.log file, its really messy, but i want now is that every new log comment should be come into new line.

Answer (score 6):

Use constant `PHP_EOL` (maybe even 2 times) in the end of the message for the best new line behavior in text files.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`. In some programs (ex. notepad) you will see all in one line if you not put the carriage return escape char sequence `"\r"` before new line `"\n"`.

When you use the constant `PHP_EOL` it will vary between operating systems. For example, if you run your script in Windows PHP_EOL has a value of "\r\n", but if you run the same script in linux you will get only "\n".